# Кнопка Like/Unlike

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails

Я пытаюсь сделать кнопку лайков. Все вроде получилось, только есть одна проблема после клика не обновляется количество лайков

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :posts do
   match :vote, on: :member, via: [:post, :delete]
end

#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def vote
      @user = current_user
      @post = Post.find params[:id]
      if request.post?
         @user.like!(@post)
      elsif request.delete?
         @user.unlike!(@post)
      end
      respond_to do |format|
         format.js #-> only XHR allowed
      end
   end
end

#app/views/posts/vote.js.erb
$(".likes").html("<%=j render 'posts/vote' %>");

#app/views/posts/_vote.html.erb
<% if user_signed_in?%>
   <% method = current_user.likes?(@post) ? ["delete", ""] : ["post", "un"] %>
   <%= link_to image_tag("#{method[1]}like.png", alt: "#{method[1]}like"), vote_post_path(@post), remote: true, method: method[0].to_sym %>
   <%= @post.likers_count if @post.likers_count>0 %> 
<% end %>

#app/views/posts/show.html.erb
<div class="likes">
   <%= render partial: "vote" %>
</div>
```

Comment: Посмотрите в консоли браузера, что возвращает аякс запрос, когда ставите лойс.

Comment: при нажатиях в консоле ничего не появляется

Comment: Добавь в #app/views/posts/vote.js.erb 'alert('123');', например. Посмотри, будет ли он срабатывать.

Comment: Надо смотреть: а. какие запросы идут по нажатию (вкладочка "сеть" в файрбаге), б. что происходит в консоли сервера. Эту информацию сюда.